# Regex for a specefic pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone help me the regex pattern in PHP for the following pattern?

```
<letter><letter><space><digit><digit><letter><space><letter><letter><letter><letter>
```

I have already tried it with following pattern:

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z].{2}[ ].{1}[0-9].{2}[a-zA-Z].{1}[ ].{1}[a-zA-Z].{4}/",$word)) {
          $response = "Not valid";
        }
```

but the above is not working.

Comment: pattern:<letter><letter><space><digit><digit><letter><space><letter><letter><letter><letter>

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to check whether my given string is matching with this particular pattern:

Comment: Example word: WB 24A 0824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2} [0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$
```

**Code:**

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]{2} [0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$/', $word)) {
   $response = "Not valid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
>

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]{2}\s[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}\s[a-zA-Z]{4}/",$word)) { $response = "Not valid"; }
```